# Cordova upload multiple files

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, windows-phone-8.1, phonegap-plugins

I have been working on a project that is based on **Cordova** Phonegap to **Windows Phone** application and I wanted to upload multiple files to a server using ***one request*** with other form data.

Can I do that with JQuery Ajax and can File Upload of Cordova API send multiple files to server in one request.

Comment: file upload can only upload a file, try using an input type file and AJAX

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with Ajax - `jQuery.post()`, create a html form with 2 or more file upload input fields, then create a php API on your server with the applicaple coding to receive and upload multiple files to your server from the .POST. After all is said and done; Once you click submit from the form, the data should be sent to your Ajax setup > then to your API for processing.